# What does making sure "that your theme is Wordpress header and footer tag enabled" mean?

Tags: plugins, headers

I am trying to get this plugin to work (http://wordpress.org/plugins/prettyphoto/), and there is a reference to:

> Make sure that your theme is WordPress header and footer tag enabled
>   otherwise this plugin won't work.

I don't understand what is meant by 'header and footer tag enabled'.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the Plugin developer means that you should ensure that your Theme calls the [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) (normally output in `header.php`) and [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) (normally output in `footer.php`) template tags, used to output scripts and stylesheets in the document head and foot.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it means that your theme needs to use [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) and [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer), both of which are involved in printing scripts to the page.